# Having trouble inputting into arraylist, tried everything

Tags: java

I'm trying to input data into the Stocks arraylist which contains stock objects.  a stock is made up of a symbol, number of shares, and cost per share.  This is my code, I've been stuck for hours and can't figure out why my input isn't going into the arraylist.  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stock {

 String sym;
 int amt;
 double cost;

 public stock(String sym, int amt, double cost){
  sym = this.sym;
  amt = this.amt;
  cost = this.cost;
 }

 public String getSym() {
  return sym;
 }


 public int getAmt() {
  return amt;
 }


 public double getCost() {
  return cost;
 }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return ("sym: "+this.getSym()+
                     " amt : "+ this.getAmt() +
                     " cost: "+ this.getCost());
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

 int choice = 0;
 ArrayList<stock> Stocks = new ArrayList<stock>();

 while (choice == 0){
 System.out.println("Enter 1 to input a new stock, or 2 to query a stock's price, 3 to quit: ");
 Scanner sc1 = new Scanner (System.in);
 choice = sc1.nextInt();
 }

 if(choice==1){
   Scanner sc2 = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter the stock symbol: ");
   String sym = sc2.next();
   System.out.println("Please enter the number of shares: ");
   int amt = sc2.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Please enter the price per share: ");
   double cost = sc2.nextDouble();

   stock list = new stock(sym, amt, cost);

   Stocks.add(list);

   System.out.println(Stocks.toString());

}
}
}
```

And here is my output:

```
[sym: null amt : 0 cost: 0.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field assignment is from right to left

```
sym = this.sym;
```

should be

```
this.sym = sym;
```

Same for the other `Stock` fields

Comment: WOW hahaha.  thank you very much, i will check mark it when i can